# Having problems with if and else statement

Tags: java

I'm having a bit trouble with one piece of my code. The program is supposed to print out `aapnFil` and `lesFil` methods to the screen, but when I run the program it prints out the `else` statement instead i.e. `Something went wrong`.

Here is the piece of the code I'm struggling with:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Oblig3C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OrdAnalyse ordAn = new OrdAnalyse();

        if(args.length >= 1) {
            ordAn.aapnFil(args[0]);
            ordAn.lesFil();

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
        }


    }//end of main method
}
```

What do I need to do to make the code print out the `if` statement instead of the `else` statement?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I use command prompt to execute my program.

Comment: you have to pass in one or more parameters to your program from the command line or execution environment in your IDE

Comment: What do you type on the command line? Do your `aapnFil` and `lesFil` methods print anything themselves?

Comment: Note that unlike many other languages, in Java command line argument does not include program name.

Comment: its supposed to read from a file. If I type `java Oblig3C Alice.txt` in command prompt it runs fine, but if I only type `java Oblig3C` it prints out `Something went wrong`

Comment: @Conscious: because you're not giving any parameters, thus the size of the parameter array is not equal or more than 1.

Comment: So bascially, there is nothing wrong with this code? If I added for example `System.out.print.ln("Add: java Oblig3C <textfile>");` instead of `System.out.print.ln("Something went wrong");` that would've been better for the user to understand?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add the arguments.

> java Oblig3c arg1 arg2 arg3

if you're using the command line, or add them as arguments in your startup configuration.

If you don't do this, your `main` method will not have any arguments and thus the size of the parameter array is 0.

Comment: For example would this statement be better: `System.out.print.ln("Add: java Oblig3C <textfile>");` instead of `Something went wrong`?

Answer (score 0):

In command line you can pass arguments to the args[] in main method separated by a space

```
java className arg1 arg2 arg3
```

So here what happens is since you are not passing any arguments

```
args.length = 0
```